# OperationalError: (1414, 'OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine 'stored procedure name' is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger')

Tags: stored-procedures, parameter-passing, airflow, mysql-python, out

I am having issues in calling stored procedure with out parameter in python using Airflow mysqlhook

signature of the stored procedure is 
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_stage_processdata`(out p_status INT)

src_cursor.execute("CALL sp_stage_processdata(%s);", (status,))

i am getting error

OperationalError: (1414, 'OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine sp_stage_processdata is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

I tried removing out parameter and procedure executes well with python so there is nothing wrong.

I am not able to use cursor.callproc because of version issue.

Answer (score 2):

When using `OUT` you need to pass a MySQL variable to your call and you cannot pass a value directly.

It should look something like:

```
CALL sp_stage_processdata(@p_status)
```

If you need to process the value you pass, you can have 2 options:

1. change the `OUT` to `INOUT` and use `SET @p_status` and than call your procedure
2. split your procedure to use `IN` and `OUT` like the following:

   `sp_stage_processdata(out p_status_out INT, IN p_status)`

   So you can call your procedure like this:

   `src_cursor.execute("CALL sp_stage_processdata(@p_status_out, %s);", (status,))`